# Remembering a checkbox status in localstorage onload?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome Extension in which a user defaultly sees one div on load but can check checkboxes revealing (or hiding) other divs which I want to persist even after the page is closed.

My HTML is:

```
  <input id="click" type="checkbox"></input>
<div class="newnote">
<center><div class="note2">
    <img src="http://s1.postimg.org/7rpakqgqn/notebook1.png" draggable= "false"></div></center>
<center><div id = "content2">
<div id= "tcontent2" contenteditable="true" data-ph= " Make a note . . . "
style= "height: 300px; overflow: auto"></div>
</div></center>
</div>

<input id="clicktwo" type="checkbox"></input>
<div class="newnotetwo">
<center><div class="note3">
    <img src="http://s1.postimg.org/7rpakqgqn/notebook1.png" draggable= "false"></div></center>
<center><div id = "content3">
<div id= "tcontent3" contenteditable="true" data-ph= " Make a note . . . "
style= "height: 300px; overflow: auto"></div>
</div></center>
</div>
```

and my JS is (currently only for 'clicktwo' checkbox):

```
function save(){
var checkbox = document.getElementById('clicktwo');
localStorage.setItem('clicktwo', checkbox.checked);
}

function load(){    
var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('clicktwo'));
document.getElementById("clicktwo").checked = checked;
}

function wis(){
location.reload();
localStorage.clear()

}
```

My question is, why isn't this working? I've cross referenced a few sources but still find myself lost. Any and all help will be appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add event listeners to checkbox onclick event

   function checkBoxClick(event) { ... };
2. callback function will be called with atribute - event. Ithrough it you can get the HTML of the clicked node and it's attributes.
3. feed these attributes to persist function:

   function persist(elementId, checkBoxState) { 
       /*set to localStorage["elementId"] = checkBoxState; */
   };

Now you have you data changes persisted.

4. During page load get the values from localStorage and make correspondent changes to UI.

**N.B.** It's a good idea to have an array of objects `{id: "id_of_checkbox", state: "is_checked?"}` and save to localStorage whole array at once ( under one name ).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still a bit of a newcomer to JS so was wondering if you could show me the code?